# Trying to open file with PHP-FFMpeg after it was encoded once

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

in the same PHP process I'm trying to open a file that was manipulated and saved, and then I'm trying to open it with as a new FFMpeg\Video. For example, in the same process:

```
Open -> original.MOV
  Manipulate & save to -> new.mp4
    Open -> new.mp4
```

However when I'm trying to open the manipulated file I get this InvalidArgumentException exception:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to detect file format, only audio and video supported
```

It's thrown by the FFMpeg::open() after it could not detect that it's a either Video or Audio stream.

**FFMpeg::open()**

> ```
> public function open($pathfile)
> {
>     if (null === $streams = $this->ffprobe->streams($pathfile)) {
>         throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to probe "%s".', $pathfile));
>     }
>
>     if (0 < count($streams->videos())) {
>         return new Video($pathfile, $this->driver, $this->ffprobe);
>     } elseif (0 < count($streams->audios())) {
>         return new Audio($pathfile, $this->driver, $this->ffprobe);
>     }
>
>     throw new InvalidArgumentException('Unable to detect file format, only audio and video supported');
> }
> ```

The filters I applied to the video are audio mute and speedup (setpts).

*So I wonder, why FFMpeg doesn't recognise it as video?*

Comment: What ffmpeg command was applied to the MOV?

Comment: Basically if I had to convert it to ffmpeg it would probably be: ffmpeg -i  tests/clips/originals/clip1.MOV  -vf  'setpts=(1/5)*PTS' -an  tests/clips/video_1.mp4

Comment: Looks good. You need to read in the actual error reported by FFmpeg, sent to stderr.

Comment: Well, I use Monolog for logging and I see logs only of ffprobe commands and no ffmpeg :/

Comment: Since you're using ffprobe to probe, what do those logs say?

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake inside my code where I tried to a load a corrupted video file. Thank you @Mulvya for helping my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was trying to open a video file that was corrupted or incomplete. Anyway, the problem wasn't with the code or god forbid - php-ffmpeg.